# Grails custom environment

Tags: grails

when I try to make use of custom environments in grails by setting the environment name like

```
grails -Dgrails.env=demo run-app
```

I only get an error message saying

```
Script 'demo' not found, did you mean: ...
```

It seems that this problem only exists in a windows environment - on linux, everything works fine...

Sorry, I've forgotten to mention that I use Grails v 2.0.3

Comment: Have you tried just using `grails demo run-app`?

Comment: Ok, just curious. I've not used custom environments, so I've got no other suggestions :/

Comment: What version of Grails are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

found a solution:

windows needs the quotation marks around the parameter:

```
grails "-Dgrails.env=demo" run-app
```

this works for both OS: windows and  linux!

**Update:**

It seems that only the windows powershell needs the quotation marks, but linux accepts them, too:

```
grails "-Dgrails.env=demo" run-app
```

For windows cmd.exe, you have to use the statement without the quotation marks:

```
grails -Dgrails.env=demo run-app
```

horrible.

Comment: Good find! You should send Microsoft a bill for your wasted time :)  Also you should accept your answer so others know it is a verified solution.